# find out which triangle is closest to equilateral triangle, fastest/simplest way

Tags: math, geometry

I have tons of triangles defined by three 3d points, like

```
T1 = ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3))
T2 = ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3))
T3 = ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3))
T4 = ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3))....
```

What I would like to know is, what is the best way to figure out which of these triangle is closest to equilateral triangle.
The best strategy I can think of is, somehow calculate three internal angles of each triangle then get product of those three angles, then see which triangle has biggest product. If I'm not mistaking, closer the triangle is to equilateral triangle product of three angles is bigger(when a triangle is perfect equilateral triangle the product of internal angles is 60 times 60 times 60 = 216000)
However, I feel like there are much better way to do this task.
I would appreciate if you could comes up with better solution for me.
None of those sets of three 3d points are in straight line.
There are no edges whose length is 0 in these triangles.

Comment: [This](https://mrhonner.com/archives/6165) seems like an interesting idea, especially when coupled with Heron's formula for area.

Comment: thanks, this method sounds good

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the insight, I decided to go with this method. I will mark it as an solved if you post this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [clever idea](https://mrhonner.com/archives/6165) due to a math teacher from Brooklyn, New York named Patrick Honner. It is to take the ratio of the area of a triangle to the area of the equilateral triangle which has the same perimeter. This yields a number between 0 and 1, with 1 corresponding to perfectly equilateral. When combined with [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area of a triangle, you get a fairly easy computation (especially after combining to a single square root and simplifying).

Here is a Python implementation:

```
import math

#computation given the sides:

def eq(a,b,c):
    p = a+b+c
    s = p/2
    e = p/3
    return math.sqrt((s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)/(s-e)**3)

def dist(p,q):
    return math.sqrt(sum((x-y)**2 for x,y in zip(p,q)))

#computation given the vertices:
    
def eq_vertices(vertices):
    p,q,r = vertices
    a = dist(p,q)
    b = dist(p,r)
    c = dist(q,r)
    return eq(a,b,c)

def most_equilateral(triangles):
    return max(triangles,key = eq_vertices)
```

For testing purposes I wrote:

```
import random

def rand_triangle():
    nums = tuple(random.uniform(0,10) for _ in range(9))
    return nums[:3],nums[3:6],nums[6:]

def rand_triangles(n):
    return [rand_triangle() for _ in range(n)]

p,q,r = most_equilateral(rand_triangles(10**6))
print(p)
print(q)
print(r)
print(dist(p,q),dist(p,r),dist(q,r))
```

Typical output:

```
(5.78980790676774, 9.853230008053409, 4.974470485333855)
(8.824990996578379, 4.403159314576518, 3.1039937224539615)
(2.7571861861239597, 5.607135338917225, 1.0725696230700976)
6.512625451616404 6.515438955183434 6.511105693852511
```

Generating the 1 million triangles takes longer than finding the most equilateral one. If speed is an issue, you could consider removing the sqrt from the function `eq` since that would still yield a function taking values in the range [0,1].

Comment: thanks for posting as answer and sample script as well, I found it very awkward to post an answer to my own question.  Thank you kindly. and Yes, I don't need sqrt() function, as all I want to know is which one is the closest to equilateral triangle, I don't need to know exact ratio of area of each triangle and area of equilateral triangle of same perimeter.